# An alternative proof for Bertrand's Postulate when $n \ge 36$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers, factorial

I've been thinking about how factorials compare to [primorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial).  I have not seen this argument before.  If I made a mistake, please call it out.  :-)

Let $x+1, x+2, \dots, x+n$ be a sequence of consecutive integers.

Let $r_{x,1},r_{x,2},\dots,r_{x,n}$ have the following properties:

- $r_{x,i} | (x+i)$
- $r_{x,1}, r_{x,2}, \dots, r_{x,n}$ are all relatively prime to each other.
- $\prod\limits_{i \le n}r_{x,i}$ is the least common multiple for $x+1, x+2, \dots, x+n$

Example:

- Let $x=35, n=5$ so that we have $36, 37, 38, 39, 40$
- $r_{35,1}=9, r_{35,2} = 37, r_{35,3} = 19, r_{35,4}=13, r_{35,5}=40$
- Each $r_i$ is relatively prime to each other and the product of all equals the least commmon multiple.

Let $r(x,n) = \prod\limits_{i \le n}r_{x,i}$

Claim 1:  For $x \ge 36$, $\pi(x) \le \left\lfloor\frac{x}{3}\right\rfloor$

> Except for $2,3$ all primes are $6x+1$ or $6x+5$.
>
> If $x \ge 36$:
>
> $\pi(x) \le \pi(36) + \left\lfloor\frac{x+1-36}{6}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{x+5-36}{6}\right\rfloor \le \left\lfloor\frac{66}{6}+\frac{x-35}{6} + \frac{x-31}{6}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac{x}{3}\right\rfloor$

Claim 2:  For $n \ge 36$, assuming no primes between $n$ and $2n$, there are at least $\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{3}\right\rfloor$ instances of distinct $i$ where $r_{n,i}=1$.

Note: These instances could occur anywhere between $n$ and $2n$.

> Since $r_{n,1}, r_{n,2}, \dots, r_{n,n}$ are relatively prime to each other and there are less than or equal to $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor$ primes, the rest must be $1$ and since each prime is uniquely found in one and only one $r_{n,i}$

Claim 3: For $n \ge 36$, $\dfrac{(2n)!}{n![r(n,n)]} \ge \dfrac{\left(n+\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{3}\right\rfloor\right)!}{n!}$ and $r(n,n) \le \dfrac{(2n)!}{\left(2n-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor\right)!}$

> Both of these follow directly from Claim 2:
>
> - $r(n,n) < \dfrac{(2n)!}{\left(2n-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor\right)!}$ since there at most $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor$ instances where $r_{n,i}\ne1$ and the product of any such instances is less  than or equal to $\dfrac{(2n)!}{\left(2n-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor\right)!}$
> - $\dfrac{(2n)!}{n![r(n,n)]} > \dfrac{\left(n+\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{3}\right\rfloor\right)!}{n!}$ since $\dfrac{(2n)!}{n![r(n,n)]} = \prod\limits_{i \le n \text{ and } r_{n,i}=1} (n+i)$ and there are at least $\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{3}\right\rfloor$ instances where $r_{n,i}=1$ and the product of any $\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{3}\right\rfloor$ instances will be greater or equal to $\dfrac{\left(n+\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{3}\right\rfloor\right)!}{n!}$.

Claim 4: $\dfrac{\left(n+\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{3}\right\rfloor\right)!}{n!} >  \dfrac{(2n)!}{\left(2n-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor\right)!}$

> - $\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{3}\right\rfloor \ge 2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor$
> - The product of any two instances of $(n+i)(n+j)$ will be greater than $(n+1)(n+2) = n^2+3n + 2 > 2n$ for $n \ge 1$.
> - It follows that the $\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{3}\right\rfloor$ can be ordered into $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor$ pairs of $2$ instances.

Claim 5: For $n \ge 36$, it is impossible that there are no primes between $n$ and $2n$.

> Since $\dfrac{\left(n+\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{3}\right\rfloor\right)!}{n!} >  \dfrac{(2n)!}{\left(2n-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor\right)!}$, applying Claim 2 and Claim 3, it follows that:
>
> $ \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{(2n)!}{n!} < \dfrac{(2n)!}{n![r(n,n)]}$
>
> But this is impossible since $r(n,n) \ge n\# > 2$

---

**Edit 1**: I found some minor problems with Claim 2 and Claim 3.

While Claim 1 establishes that $\pi(x) \le \left\lfloor\frac{x}{3}\right\rfloor$, these primes could be at any point between $n+1$ and $2n$.  It is not correct to assume that $r_{n,i}=1$ for $i > \left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor$

I have modified argument to remove this assumption.

---

**Edit 2**:  It looks like my definition of $r_i$ does not work as I expected.

For example for the sequence $36, 37, 38, 39, 40$, by my previous definition:  $r_1=36, r_2=37, r_3 = 19, r_4=13, r_5=10$.  But then, $\gcd(r_1,r_5)=2$.

I have updated the definition which I believe fixes the issue.

---

**Edit 3**:  Removed a reference to primorial which I had missed and updated the last sentence.

It is not essential to the argument but it is incorrect.  Thanks to @mathlove for noticing it.

---

**Edit 4**:  Updated claim 3 based on comment by @JonMark Perry.

---

**Edit 5**:  Claim 5 is not valid.  See answer or comments for detail.

Comment: Why are the $r_{x,i}$ integers?

Comment: Yeah, choose  $x=i=p$ for some prime $p>2$

Comment: In your example, that would not be a problem.   In your example, $r_{x,i} = x+i$ since $x < x+1$.  On the other hand $r_{x,i+p} = \frac{x+i+p}{p}$ which is an integer.  Am I missing something? Does my update to the definition of $r_{x,i}$  address your concern?

Comment: I think that $r(n,n) = n\#$ does not hold in general. For example, $2^2$ does not divide $36\#=2\times 3\times 5\times\cdots\times 31$, but $2^2$ divides $r(36,36)=\text{lcm}(36+1,36+2,\cdots, 36+36)$.

Comment: Yes.  I tried to clean up all the references to primorials.  That was the mistake that I fixed in edit 2.  I will update it.  Thanks very much for catching it.  I don't think it is critical to the argument which rests on $r_{x,i}$ being relatively prime to each other.

Comment: You might want to edit the last sentence before "Edit 1".

Comment: Nice catch.  I updated the last sentence before "Edit 1" so it should now be good.  Thanks very much!  :-)

Comment: I think your arguments in Claim 1, 2, 3, 4 are fine, but I can't understand how you get $\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{(2n)!}{n!} < \dfrac{(2n)!}{n![r(n,n)]}$ from Claim 2, 3 and 4. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: That looks like my mistake!  I made an assumption that is not valid.  Thanks very much for catching it!  I realize that if $a > b$, it does not follow that $a > \frac{ab}{2}$ since it follows that $1 > \frac{b}{2}$ which is definitely not true.  Thanks very much!

Comment: your proof of claim 3 proves $\le$, but the statement claims $\lt$

Comment: @JonMark Perry, thanks for noticing!  I will update the claim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claim $5$ claims too much. We only have:

$$\frac{(2n)!}{n![r(n,n)]} \ge \frac{\left(n+\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{3}\right\rfloor\right)!}{n!} \ge \dfrac{(2n)!}{\left(2n-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor\right)!} \ge r(n,n)$$

Comment: I agree the question is great, and there was a bounty, but only one upvote? Usually the balance is the other way. +1